# Using Atmega 128 as real time logic units

Tags: interrupt, avr, atmel, piano

[image]Currently I'm designing simple digital piano model. I used tons of decoders and And's to build my project. In simulation those ANDs are connected and enables external int0. So that If any button is pressed, this triggers button play function regardless of other processes. But in PCB and soldering i find these ANDs quite annoying. So I'm trying to omit those ANDs by changing my code. Is there any software interrupts that triggers automatically if any single input reaches zero? Or FPGA like component in Atmega 128? or do I have to write button scanning code in every single lines of my main code(I scanned datasheet but didn't reached success)

74148 is 8 to 3 encoder

Comment: " Is there any software interrupts that triggers automatically if any single input reaches zero?" - Can't the external interrupts be configured to trigger low active?

Comment: the problem is there is only one pin for one interrupt but i used tons of buttons. To solve this I used AND gates for each buttons and big AND gate which is connected to INT0 and other AND's gates. It's like (A*B)*(C*D)*(E*F)*... so on

Comment: maybe show your schematic. not sure if we got your problem. if you AND all your inputs how do you know which was pressed? Also atmega128 is a bit old. more modern AVRs have an activatable pin change interupt on every input. maybe consider upgrading to an atmega1284

Comment: Since I'm beginner, Teacher prohibited to use too super controllers. So that we can understand minor and major problems about designing (like these).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lots of keys, you may want to use a series of parallel-in shift registers (e.g. 74HC(T)165 ... 8 keys per unit) - daisy chained to each other - and read their values all at once every 10 ms or so using the ATMega128 **SPI interface**.

[further reading](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11979)

Comment: That's good idea too. But I used timer interrupt. And thanks for your kindness mister

Answer (score 0):

well, if your timming is 'slow' you can easily implement a diode AND replacing all the ANDs with 1n4148 diodes (cathode to the 74148) and a unique pull up resistor to all the anodes... when any input drives the diode to GND it will pull down the INTERRUPT on the avr...

with a proper pull-up (4.7k) you can reach a 10us frame time of response (maybe more)